# What does the "In-line" in SIMM and DIMM memory mean?

Tags: memory, ram

I've been searching for what exactly  the "in-line" part means but I don't get it. Is it the way the chips are positioned, as in a line? If it is, is there another possible configuration?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The "in-line" is about all the contacts being in a straight line on the edge of the PCB.

The SIMM has only actually one set of contacts: the contacts on either side of the PCB are connected.

You can see that [on a photo of the slot](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:SIMM#/media/File:30pin_SIMM_RAM_slots,_from_an_Atari_STE_motherboard.jpg); there is only one contact for both sides.

[image: SIMM Slot in an ATARI STE]
<sup>source: wikimedia user Wolfgang "Darkoneko" ten Weges</sup>

On a DIMM, both sides of the PCB carry one line of *different* contacts:

[image: DIMM Slot on a PC motherboard, I'd guess.]
<sup>source: [wikimedia](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:DIMM#/media/File:Four_SDRAM_DIMM_slots_on_a_computer_motherboard.jpg) user Project Keil</sup>

Comment: The "in-line" in contrast to the previously common DIP and ZIP memory, which was just plain ICs you put in sockets: https://oldcomputer.info/pc/board_mem/exp1.jpg (Imagine the fun you had if you bent just one of those legs)